# Wrong layout file is being inflated

Tags: android, layout

While trying to support my app for multiple screen, i observed that wrong layout file is being inflated by the system.
I have two directories for layout. First one is layout and second directory is layout-sw420dp. Both of the directories have layout file activity_main.xml.
Now when i run my app on moto g6 which is 424 ppi/dpi.the layout file which is being loaded is from layout directory.

Comment: `sw***dp` is based on the software DPI value, which could be completely different from the hardware one. You shouldn't be targeting hardware DPIs for that reason.

Answer (score 0):

According to this site https://www.gsmarena.com/motorola_moto_g6-9000.php the Moto G6 has the following display:

- 1080 x 2160 pixels, 18:9 ratio (~424 ppi density)

You can determine its `dp` width with the following formula:

- `px-width` / (`ppi` / `160`)
- `1080` / (`424` / `160`)

Which gives ~407. Therefore, if you want to target this phone using the `swXXXdp` resource qualifier, you should use `sw407dp` instead of `sw420dp`.

It's important to note that the value for `swNNNdp` is based on the *smallest width* in dp, which is a **function** of screen density, but it is *not* based *solely* on screen density.

Comment: I tried with layout-sw407dp but system still inflates the wrong layout file. According to this page the width is 360 dp http://www.emirweb.com/ScreenDeviceStatistics.php#Header2185 . And the system select the wrong file for any value > 360 dp

Comment: It's possible that the website I linked has the wrong values for the device's pixel width or density. If it seems to have 360dp width, then you'd need to use `sw360dp`

Comment: Indeed, the website you linked says that the device has `xxhdpi` density, which usually means 480 dpi. 1080 / (480 / 160) = 360dp